# Want to use dropdown cc button to excute a javascript function as well passes unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the button I am using to activate the function **PlayCard("data")** where obj is passed to be used later. (**Working fine, but this is not I want**)

```
<div class='dropdown'>
<button class='dropbtn class2' onclick=PlayCard("data")>Play</button>
</div>
```

But **I want to use**  a dropdown button from bootstrap which calls the function PlayCard("obj") and passes some unique value like 1, 2 ,3  etc instead of href = "#".

```
<div class='dropdown' >
<button class='btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown'>Test<span class='caret'></span>
</button>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'> 
<li><a href='#''>Value1</a> </li> 
<li><a href='#'>Value2</a> </li> 
<li><a href='#'>Value3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

But I don't know how to pass the function PlayCard("data") as well as some unique value when there is onclick on **Value1, Value2, or Value3**.

This is the reason why I need both the PlayCard("data") and Value associated with Value1, Value2 and Value3 option.

**code.js**

```
function PlayCard(data)
{
 var obj = _.find(data, function(obj){ return obj.total == data; });
if (value == 1)
{
  Function1(obj);
}
elseif (value == 2)   
{
  Function2(obj);
}
else   
{
  Function3(obj);
}
};
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking...

Comment: @spencerlarry I want to use execute funtion PlayCard(data) from button, and there are 3 more functions as you can see, which will be executed depending on what is selected from the dropdown button. It means to execute Function1 or Function2 or Function3, PlayCard need to be called.

Answer (score 0):

For a dropdown, you'll probably want to use change instead of click. You can then read the value in and make your changes accordingly.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

```
 <form>

  <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1">

  <select class="target">

    <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>

    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>

  </select>

</form>


$( ".target" ).change(function() {

  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );

});
```

To read 1, 2, 3 you'll do something like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
$('select').on('change', function() {
  PlayerCard( this.value ); //read in the value and do something with it, like passing it to your PlayerCard 
})
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, can you please tell me , how I am going to use the function PlayCard and the values 1, 2 or 3 ?
I am new to this. Sorry

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. You'll want to read in the values from your dropdown using .change and then pass that value into your PlayerCard function. Make sense?

Comment: And what about the "data" which is another parameter, that need to be passed simultaneously, and need to be associated in the html part i.e with button only.

Comment: can we do soemthing like this,

<select>
    <option class = "data" value="1">One</option>
    <option class = "data" value="2">Two</option>
    <option class = "data" value="3">Three</option>
</select>

and this data can be used in the PlayCard function ?

Comment: You can read your data value within the same change function: http://jsfiddle.net/csLAk/8518/